# Does the Event api expose what fbid's a user has invited to that event?

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api

I'm interested in measuring how many other fb friends a facebook user invites to a given event. Ideally which specific users that user invited to the event as well as the number of users.

Related, I'm also interested in measuring how many/which facebook users a user invites to a facebook fan page.

Answer (score 0):

The [Graph API Event object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) contains an `owner` field, which identifies the User ID of the profile that created each event.

The [/invited endpoint on that Event object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/#invited) contains a list of Users that were invited to that particular Event.

The [Graph API User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#events) has an /events endpoint which lets you see the list of events that a User is attending. Users are always attending events which they have created.

If you put these 3 things together, you will be able to do what you want :)